# GWT client request not getting posted to server

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a small GWT application that gets the contents for a FlexTable from a database based on some string parameters. It is triggered by the click of a button on the GUI.

Everything works as expected when the app is initially started. But, upon multiple clicks (requests), the app stops working and my requests from the client no longer reaches the sever code. I am running on hosted mode and have breakpoints in my code. I can trace the code on client side; but after it submits the request to server using my service instance, it never reaches the server; nor the onSuccess() gets called.

Can someone please help me debug this? Where should i start to see traces of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it wasnt anything about GWT RPC. The request was indeed getting submitted to server but because of a db resource contention, Eclipse wasn't showing me any trace of the code on server side. I switched on debug loggings in the code and everything because real clear.

Thanks!
pjames